# Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi /2}\cot^n(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Does anyone know how to deal with the integral
$$\int_0^{\pi /2}\cot^n(x)dx$$

with $n\in (-1,1)$?

Apparently it is a well known identity: it is listed in the [page of wolfram for the cotangent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cotangent.html), where it says that it equals $2^{-1}\pi \sec [2^{-1} (\pi n)]$

Thanks in advance for any solution or hint!

Comment: That result is valid only for $|n|<1$.  The integral diverges of $|n|>\ge 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $|n|<1$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\cot^n(x)\,dx&=\frac12 B\left(\frac{1-n}{2},\frac{1+n}{2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12 \Gamma\left(\frac{1-n}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1+n}{2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sin\left(\pi \frac{1+n}{2}\right)}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\cos(n\pi/2)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly the first step? I don't quite follow how to transform it into a beta function.

Comment: Sure.  Note that $B(x,y)=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt$.  Now, substitute $t=\sin^2(u)$.  Then, let $x=(1-n)/2$ and $y=(1+n)/2$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha\in(-1,1)$
$$I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cot^{\alpha}(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan^{\alpha}(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^{\alpha}}{1+t^2}\,dt $$
and the last integral boils down to a value of the [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) through the substitution $\frac{1}{1+t^2}=u$. We get:

> $$ I(\alpha) = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2\cos\frac{\pi\alpha}{2}}} $$

as a consequence of the [reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula).

Comment: That isn't the correct answer Jack.  The denominator should be cosine.

Comment: @Dr.MV: right, thanks. Now fixed.

Comment: You're welcome.  ;-))